# How do I add more parameters to this line. Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a multiline dropdown menu with multiple options, what I currently have is a line of code that has only one dependency, 'M100007' I want to add more. Explained in the example below.

This is the line of code :

```
selectedBusLine1 = newValue == 'M100007' ? businessLine2_01 : businessLine2_02;
```

I want to add more "newValue" values and not just one.

For example :

```
if "M100007" is selected then businessLine2_01,
if "M100008" is selected then businessLine2_02,
if "M100009" is selected then businessLine2_03,
if "M100010" is selected then businessLine2_04,
if "M100011" is selected then businessLine2_05,
if "M100012" is selected then businessLine2_06, 
and so on...
```

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add like this

```
selectedBusLine1 = newValue == 'M100007'
    ? businessLine2_01
    : newValue == 'M100008'
      ? businessLine2_02
      : newValue == 'M100009'
        ? businessLine2_03
        : newValue == 'M100010' 
          ? businessLine2_03 
          : newValue == 'M100011';
```

Comment: this is not so readable like switch or if, or the best answer by @Apealed

Answer (score 3):

I recommend creating a `Map` to create a one-to-mapping of the string to you `businessLine2_01`-like objects

```dart
final mappedValues = {
  'M100007' : businessLine2_01,
  'M100008' : businessLine2_02,
  'M100009' : businessLine2_03,
  'M100010' : businessLine2_04,
  // and so on..
};

final myValue = mappedValues['M100007']; // this is businessLine2_01
```

Answer (score 2):

Better try using `switch` and `case` statements.
For ex:

```
String selectedBus1 = "";
switch(newValue) {
  case "M100010":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_02;
     break;
  }
  case "M100011":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_03;
     break;
  }
  case "M100012":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_04;
     break;
  }
  case "M100013":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_05;
     break;
  }
  default: {
    selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_default;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String selectedBus1 = "";
switch(newValue) {
  case "M100010":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_02;
     break;
  }
  case "M100011":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_03;
     break;
  }
  case "M100012":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_04;
     break;
  }
  case "M100013":{
     selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_05;
     break;
  }
  default: {
    selectedBus1 = buisnessLine2_default;
  }
}
```